# JavaScript open new window, but focus shoud remain on old window

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Objective** :

I want to open a new window but the focus remain on old window.

**what I tried :**

```
<button id="test">Open Google</button>
```

-

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", openNewBackgroundTab, false);

function openNewBackgroundTab(){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "http://www.google.com/";
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");    
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, 
                        window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                        true, false, false, false, 
                        0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Here is the link : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/5/)

This works fine in Chrome but not in Mozilla.

Please help !!

Comment: reset focus on test? document.getElementById("test").focus(); after creating a new window.

Comment: window.opener.focus();

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is up to the browser and can't be controlled by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

write onload event  of the new window

```
window.opener.focus();
```

Comment: we are redirecting to third party site ,if so how is this possible ?

Comment: I tried <a href '#' onclick="window.open('#','_self');  window.open('http://www.google.com/','_blank'); 
window.opener.focus();"></a>  But this opening the new window on Left side ,any possibility to open right side ?