# How to open new page in background all browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to open new window but to stay focused in the current page, code:

```js
var strUrl = "http://www.google.com";
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = strUrl;
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

The code above work perfect in Chrome but not in IE, FireFox.

Comment: So, wait, what you are doing is simulating a Ctrl-click on a dynamically generated link. Wouldn't that be pure coincidence that that opens a window in a certain way? What if I change the bindings in my browser? What if my browser has different bindings by default? I don't think this is a safe solution. And I don't think it can be made cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Check also [here. Same question, same answer. It does not and cannot work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606498/javascript-open-new-window-but-focus-shoud-remain-on-old-window?rq=1) - and it shouldn't: Why should the browser leave it up to you to jiggle around new windows? That has been frowned upon since the days of Netscape 3. ;-)